# Installing and Starting old network (.BNA) files in hlf1.4

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I created a network (.BNA) and this installs and starts successfully under hlfv12 using composer v20.9 network install and composer network start commands).
All other components (e.g. composer-rest-server and composer-playground) work fine.

I have successfully installed hlf 1.4 and can get the sample, first-network, generated, up and down.

How can I install and start my old network (.BNA) under hlf 1.4? I understand Composer v20.9 does still work under hlf1.4.

Thanks.

Comment: There is no difference between deploying it between a 1.2 fabric and a 1.4 fabric. Note that composer did provide a simple preconfigured fabric at the 1.2 level and created the connection profile and generated the admin card on your behalf. You would have to do that yourself.

Comment: Hi David Thanks for the prompt response. Is there any info on the web as to how I go about creating the connection profiles and generate the admin cars etc. under 1.4. Up till now, I have completely relied on the Composer and haven't got much knowledge/experience of what it did under the hood. Obviously now I'll have to learn it but just wondering if there is a fast track to that. Thanks.

Comment: Composer has 2 Deploying type tutorials which provide all the info needed about how to construct connection profiles and cards etc. As composer is now deprecated I would recommend not wasting too much time on it now.